# Errors in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to generate an R markdown document which consists of chunks of code consisting of ggplot2 and corrplot graphics and summary statistics using the summary functions.

However, as soon as I am trying to generate the R markdown document using the following chunk of code

```
## Nurse Bed (fine; see notes)

summary(df3$nurseBed)
summary(df4$nurseBed)
summary(df5$nurseBed)
summary(d$nurseBed)

hist(d$nurseBed, col = "orange", main = "Before Exterme/Outlier Value is Removed")

tail(sort(d$nurseBed),10)

outlier <- d[which(d$nurseBed > 40),]                                     #     identify 
outlier <- d[which(d$nurseBed > 40),c("Code","Year","Period","nurseBed")] #     the outlier 
                                                                          #      and  remove it
d[c(101,265),"nurseBed"] <- NA

hist(d$nurseBed, col = "pink", main = "After Exterme/Outlier Value is Removed")
boxplot(d$nurseBed, col = "pink", main = "Box Plot for Nurse Bed ratio after the outlier/extreme values")

tail(sort(d$nurseBed),10)
summary(d$nurseBed)
IQR(d$nurseBed, na.rm = TRUE)

# Identify the extreme values for nursebed ratio after the removal

select(d, Code, Trust, Year, Specialists, nurseBed) %>%
  filter(nurseBed > 4.2) %>%
  arrange(nurseBed)

plot(df3$nurseBed, df3$TFPscore, main = "Nurse Bed Ratio and Productivity", xlab = "TFP", ylab = "Nurse Bed",
 col = "blue")
cor(df3$nurseBed, df3$TFPscore, use = "complete.obs")
plot(df3[df3$Specialists==0,]$nurseBed, df3[df3$Specialists==0,]$TFPscore, 
 main = "Nurse Bed Ratio and Productivity excluding Specialists", xlab = "TFP", ylab = "Nurse Bed",
 col = "red")
cor(df3[df3$Specialists==0,]$nurseBed, df3[df3$Specialists==0,]$TFPscore, use = "complete.obs")

# Revert to original data 

d <- df[df$Year %in% c("2010/11", "2011/12", "2012/13"),]
```

Its showing me the following error message:

Quitting from lines 1715-1757 (test.Rmd) 
Error in hist.default(d$nurseBed, col = "orange", main = "Before Exterme/Outlier Value is Removed") : 
  'x' must be numeric
Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> hist -> hist.default
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
Execution halted

Do excuse me if my question is naive but I am new to R markdown and I have looked for help in other sources but to no avail

The code in normal R console however works fine.

Comment: `d$nurseBed` is either `NULL` or not numeric by the time you reach this line. restart your r session and go through the chunks sequentially until you get to this one and examine the object `d`

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help! I in fact it works when I move the above chunk of code in a separate R markdown file. I think, there is something in the previous chunk(s) where I created corrplots or matrix plots that may have caused this issue.